# Is $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{O(f(x)^k)}{k!} = O(e^{f(x)})$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, exponential-function

Let f be a real function and $h_k$ an infinite sequence of functions such that $h_k(x) \in O(f(x)^k)$ as $x \to \infty$.
Assuming the series $\sum \frac{h_k(x)}{k!}$ converges for all $x$.
Is the following correct:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{h_k(x)}{k!} \in O(e^{f(x)})
\quad\text{as $x \to\infty$}
\quad?
$$
Otherwise, what should be the extra assumptions on $f$?

Thanks.

Comment: If you assume there is a single constant $C$ such that $h_k(x)\leq Cf(x)^k$, then clearly $\sum h_k(x)/k!\leq C e^{f(x)}$. If not, then letting $h_k = c_k f^k$ for a sequence $c_k$ tending to infinity will probably show that in general your statement isn't true.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly false. The notation $a(x) = O(b(x))$ is about "size", i.e., the absolute value of these functions. In this context the notation means $|a(x)| \le C|b(x)|$ for $x>0$ large enough. Thus for a counterexample, if we let $f(x) = -x,$ and $h_k(x) = x^k,$ then $h_k(x) = O(f(x)^k)$ (uniformly), yet

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{h_k(x)}{k!} = e^x,\,\, O(e^{f(x)}) = O(e^{-x}).$$

Comment: Thanks. This leads to my second question, what should be the extra assumptions? It looks like if $f$ is positive and there exists $C$ such that for all $k$, $|h_k(x)| \leq C f(x)^k$, then the result holds true. But is that a necessary condition?